# AWK: Printing a Variable Containing a Percentage Sign %

Tags: awk

I'm trying to call a variable which contains a percentage sign in it, but when I do I receive the following error.  Even when only trying to create it, it errors.  When I exclude it, my script works fine, but I want it to print this variable value in the 3rd field.

```
awk -v postutil="$postutil"
```

**Partial Output of Error:**

```
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=66%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=68%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=63%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=38%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=30%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=29%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=91%
awk: cmd. line:2:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=0%
awk: cmd. line:2:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:2: postutil=0%
awk: cmd. line:2:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

**Script:**

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r hostname interface preutil postutil criticality; do
    awk -v hostname="$hostname" -v interface="$interface" -v postutil="$postutil" '$0~ hostname "\t" interface{print hostname, interface, postutil, $0}' OFS='\t' temp/post_lsp_interfaces_02.txt
done < temp/comparison_interfaces_high_med.txt
```

**Partial of  post_lsp_interfaces_02.txt**

```
ASHBBPRJ01-CHNDDSRJ01-BE    ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae9.0   MCDLBBRJ01  ae9.0   CHNDBBRJ01  ae0.0   CHNDDSRJ01  3740.81
ASHBBPRJ01-DUKEDSRJ02-BE    ASHBBPRJ01  ae1.0   ASHBBBRJ01  ae10.0  DUKEBBRJ02  ae6.0   DUKEDSRJ02  8182.02
ASHBBPRJ01-HMRDRCRJ01-BE    ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae0.0   MRFDBBRJ01  ae4.0   NRFKBBRJ01  ae0.0   NRFKDSRJ01  ae17.0  HMRDRCRJ01  4444.66
ASHBBPRJ01-HMRDRCRJ02-BE    ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae0.0   MRFDBBRJ01  ae4.0   NRFKBBRJ01  ae6.0   VBCHBBRJ01  ae0.0   VBCHDSRJ01  ae18.0  HMRDRCRJ023125.79
ASHBBPRJ01-MCDLDSRJ01-BE    ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae9.0   MCDLBBRJ01  ae0.0   MCDLDSRJ01  3862.34
ASHBBPRJ01-MRFDDSRJ02-10-BE ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae1.0   MRFDDSRJ02  2110.26
ASHBBPRJ01-MRFDDSRJ02-11-BE ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae1.0   MRFDDSRJ02  2110.26
ASHBBPRJ01-MRFDDSRJ02-12-BE ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae1.0   MRFDDSRJ02  2110.26
ASHBBPRJ01-MRFDDSRJ02-13-BE ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae1.0   MRFDDSRJ02  2110.26
ASHBBPRJ01-MRFDDSRJ02-14-BE ASHBBPRJ01  ae2.0   ASHBBBRJ02  ae11.0  MRFDBBRJ02  ae1.0   MRFDDSRJ02  2110.26
```

**Partial of comparison_interfaces_high_med.txt**

```
ASHBBBRJ02  ae5.0   9%  31% medium_increase
DALSBBRJ02  ae10.0  34% 0%  medium_decrease
DALSBBRJ02  ae4.0   3%  44% medium_increase
DUKEBBRJ01  ae0.0   24% 75% high_increase
DUKEBBRJ01  ae5.0   56% 0%  high_decrease
DUKEBBRJ02  ae2.0   5%  57% high_increase
DUKEBBRJ02  ae6.0   15% 73% high_increase
```

Comment: you meant `... -v var2="$var2"` **-v** `var3="$var3"`, didn't you? Good luck.

Comment: I did, but the code was still accepted when I ran it.

Comment: And something like .. `awk -v FS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next} $1 in a {print $0,"test",a[$1]}' OFS="\t" file1 file2` won't do?

Comment: I've also tried "awk 'BEGIN{var1=...}'"

Comment: I ended up just using sed to remove the percent sign and then re-added it in the awk statement.

Comment: It would be better (and much faster) to have awk parse both files... you can use `NR == FNR { }` pattern to detect the first file (the *comparison* file) and store interface and postutil in arrays indexed by hostname.  When you reach the second file, you can do a `for (hostname in interface)`  loop and continue your algorithm.

Comment: By the way... `awk -v pc=$postutil 'BEGIN { print pc }'` works for me in both **gawk** and **mawk**.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using sed to remove the percent sign and then re-added it in the awk statement.